# Service WAS was not found on computer '.'

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am using Windows 7 Professional. When I am trying to start DefaultAppPool in IIS 7.0, I am getting error -

> Service WAS was not found on computer '.'.

Is there any changes in setting need to be done?

[image]